# Cover, insert and duplex print job

Tags: printing, printer

So in our office we have a Kyocera 3552ci. I have to send out a mailing with an insert from other departments. Unfortunately they were pre-printed. So I have 2 stacks of paper and a 2 sided doc to print. I need them to end up collated 1,2,3 not as 3 separate stacks. I think it can be done with Cover and Insert each pulling from a different cassette/tray than my print job.

I have been able to get 1 stack to go as a cover page and a duplex print but the insert won't print (I think because it is set to go in front of page 3 but there is no page 3). I have been able to get the cover and insert to print but it splits by duplex print into 2 single sided pages (when I tell it to print before page 2). The settings do not allow it to be printed before page 1.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Trying to clarify.
So the end result I am trying to achieve is a stack of collated/printed pages. The order that they end up in does not matter as they are all independent documents but each of the 3 sheets is a duplex (the ones delivered to me and the 1 I want to print). But I need the printer to use different trays i.e. select sheet 1 from a specific tray, sheet 2 from a different tray and sheet 3 from a 3rd tray, one of the 3 will need to be duplex printed.
Did that clarify or make things worse?

Comment: Operating system also matters A LOT as this is where the printer is getting it's commands from.  If it is Windows, please add a Windows tag (don't worry about windows-10) if Linux, please add a Linux tag.. etc.  The OS driver models are SO DIFFERENT between operating systems.. this is not a "generic printer question" as much as a question of how what feature was implemented on which OS.

Answer (score 0):

I find your break down of the problem confusing (possibly your use of "page" and "print" in 2 contexts?) but "there is no page three" is easy to fix: make one.

Make a page three that is blank. If blank pages won't print then make a page three with a single period/dot/whatever at 10% grey at an extreme edge of the printable area.

My closest guess about your issue, and assuming your output source prints all duplex (or all simplex; not mixed), it sounds like you have 1 sheet you need to print 2-sided, and then 2 sheets you simply need to collate. Set your document to 6 pages, and pad the document with blank pages as above.

If you want a "cover page 1-sided sheet; insert sheet; body text 2-sided sheet" your document would be "page 1 - cover; page 2-4 - blank; page 5-6 - body text". Set pages 3-4 (sheet 2) to print from the cassette your insert is in.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was kind of confusing to write also.

Comment: I can add a page 3 to the document but then it will print a page into the stack that will need to be removed. The end goal is to have the 3 sheets in a row, repeated. Adding the 3rd page to the printed doc will put an extra page into my stack and basically make the exercise pointless. I will try to clarify.

Comment: No problem, just be aware: in this context, the difference between a printed sheet (page) and a page (page) matters in the explanations. If I am printing a 4-page booklet, trim size 8.5h x 5.5 wide, that's one sheet of 8.5. x 11 paper (duplexed)

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just split it into 2 jobs. Not ideal but gives me the solution I am ultimately after.